# Optimize Delete

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, optimization

I have a importer system which updates the column of already existing rows in a Table. Since UPDATE was taking time I changed it to DELETE and BULK INSERT.

Here is my database setup snippet

```
Table: ParameterDefinition
Columns: Id, Name, Other Cols

Table: ParameterValue
Columns: Id, CustId, ParameterDefId, Value
```

I get the values associated to ParamterDefinition.Name from my XML source, so to import I first delete all the existing ParamterValue with all the ParamterDefinition.Name passed in the XML and finally do bulk insert of all the values from XML. Here is my query

```
DELETE FROM ParameterValue WHERE CustId = ? AND ParameterDefId IN (?,?...?);
```

For 1000 Customers the above DELETE statement is called 1000 times which is very time consuming now, approximately 64 seconds.

Is there any better way to handle DELETE of 1000 customers?

Thanks,

Sheeju

Comment: for delete the database has to still find the record to operate on it. I suggest checking the update query itself again and see why is it being slowed down.

Also, why don't you use a `transaction` which helps DB to not write the changes onto disk every single time and rather do them in a bunch when you commit. my 2 cents.

Comment: You have give us the assumption that the bottleneck is the database. But you need to identify the bottleneck before pursuing a solution. Considering that you're deleting records by foreign keys (which should be naturally indexed), I'm quite surprised by the time it's taking the DB platform to do it's job. Are you positive it's not an application issue?

Comment: @sanjeev: Update query was taking more time, lets say each customer on an average had 3 ParamterValue to be updated and 1 new ParamterValue then it would result in 3000 updates and 1000 inserts. I am already using transaction to make sure I do single commit

Comment: What about generating only a single `DELETE` statement? `where (custid = ? and parameterdefid in (..)) or (custid = ? and parameterdefid in (...)) or ...)`

Comment: _are_ these columns indexed?  it's entirely possible they're just not foreign keys at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I already tired doing OR method and this method takes much more time because for 1000 customer the lenght of DELETE statement will be huge and processing OR statement will take longer time I guess.

Comment: @Eevee: Yes they are not indexed, I will look at indexing option. Regarding Index since I am using WHERE cust_id=? AND ParamterDefId IN (?.?) do you suggest indexing cust_id and ParameterDefId?

Comment: yes, that would be a good idea, and will almost certainly eliminate your problem.  :)  you might even want a UNIQUE index across both.

Comment: Yes INDEX helped, thanks @Eevee

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table for the bulk-insert (ParameterValue_Import). Do the bulk-inserts to this table, then update/insert/delete based on the imported data.

`INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS ( .. )` for the new rows

`UPDATE .. FROM` for the updates

`DELETE FROM WHERE NOT EXISTS ( .. )` for the deletion

Bulk operations have better performance than standalone operations. Most DBMSs are designed to handle set based operations instead of record based ones.

**Edit**

To delete or update one record based on a WHERE clause which refers to only one record, the DBMS should either do a full table scan (if there is no index for the where condition) or do an index lookup. Only after the record successfully identified, the DBMS proceeds the original request (update or delete). Based on the number of records in the table and/or the size/depth of the index, this could be really expensive. This process are done for each and every command in the batch. Summing up the total cost, it could be more than if you are updating/deleting records based on another table. (Especially if the operations are update/delete nearly all records in the target table.)

When you are trying to delete/update several records at once (e.g. based on another table), the DBMS could do the lookups with only one table scan/index lookup and do a logical join when processing your request.

The cost of purely updating a record is the same in each case, just the total cost of lookup could be significantly different.

Furthermore deleting then inserting a record to update it could require more resources: when you are deleting a record, all related indexes will be updates, and when you insert the new record, the indexes will be updated once more, while with updating the record, only those indexes should be updated, which are related to an updated column (and the index update should be done only once).

Comment: Can you please explain in detailed?

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination

Answer (score 1):

I am giving the exact syntax to the above idea given by @Pred

After Bulk Insert lets say you have data in "ParamterValue_Import"

To INSERT The Records in "ParamterValue_Import" which are not in "ParamterValue"

```
INSERT INTO ParameterValue (
  CustId, ParameterDefId, Value
)
SELECT
  CustId, ParameterDefId, Value
FROM
  ParameterValue_Import
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM ParameterValue
    WHERE ParameterValue.CustId = ParameterValue_Import.CustId
);
```

To UPDATE The Records in "ParamterValue" which are also in "ParamterValue_Import"

```
UPDATE
  ParameterValue
SET
  Value = ParameterValue_Import.Value
FROM
  ParameterValue_Import
WHERE
  ParameterValue.ParameterDefId = ParameterValue_Import.ParameterDefId
  AND ParameterValue.CustId = ParameterValue_Import.CustId;
```